# How to disable the ability to save/download and image in a FancyBox gallery

Tags: fancybox-3

Hi so im making a website for a artist and he has requested that the images are made none downloadable. Im using Fancy Box and im sure some weeks ago I stumbled upon some documentation that went over this. However, I simply can not find it again. So does anyone know if there is a way to disable the save ability on Fancy Box? thanks.

Comment: You can make it require 5 clicks instead of 2, but you can't prevent it. As soon as the client browser can display the image, it is already downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

If using fancybox v3, you can use `protect` option to make it harder to download your image, example:

```
$.fancybox.defaults.protect = true;
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/wmXOqN

Comment: Your a life saver. Thanks mate really appreciate it.